# Button click listener from inside fragment

Tags: android

I usually have no problem programming the button click event when using activities, but now I'm studying `fragments` and I can't make the ButtonClick event work.

My code:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btnCadastrar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        btnCadastrar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cadastrar);
        btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnCadastrar.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("#FFFFFF"));
                Toast.makeText( getContext(), "PIMBAAA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm inflating `fragment_login`, which has the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/transp_white_rect"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Cadastrar"
            android:id="@+id/btn_cadastrar"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Besides the fact that nothing happens when I click/press the button, it appears that the button is NOT clickable.
I want some help to understand why it's not working and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking on you Fragment you will see the inflate code called 2 times.
It means 2 fragment_login's views was created on your code.

```
return view
```

instead of

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
```

because it will return a new object of fragment_login's view

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thank you! But I don't get exactly why the `listener` did not work.

Comment: You created two views . you had set listener to the first view you created but that's not visible.. the view you return at end of oncreate method will be used by fragment not the one you had set listener that's why click was not working.. mark answer as correct .